# SSL certificate for ALB on amazonaws subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I try to configure https on ALB with default amazon subdomain: some-unique-path.elb.amazonaws.com
The problem is that I can't find how to generate the ssl certificate for this domain: Amazon Certificate Manager does not allow to generate certificates for amazonaws subdomains.
Is there any way to make it without buying custom domain and configuring it for ALB?

Answer (score 1):

To use ACM you must have domain which you control. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html):

> Before the Amazon certificate authority (CA) can issue a certificate for your site, AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) **must verify that you own or control** all of the domain names that you specified in your request.

There are some free domain providers which you could maybe use, but you have to have domain under your control. You can't use `some-unique-path.elb.amazonaws.com`, because this is **AWS-owned** domain and you have no rights to it.